# WPF - Unable to bind properties of control in ContentPresenter to parent control

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, contentcontrol, contentpresenter

I have a custom control that is used in a form, this control combines a label and a textbox. When the form is in read only mode the control is changed to show a label instead of the textbox. 
To do this, I have defined a Content Template for my control, as follows:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:FormFieldControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <AdornerDecorator Grid.Column="1"
                                      Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Controls:FormFieldControl}, 
                                                   Path=IsReadOnly, 
                                                   Converter={StaticResource BooleanToInverseVisibilityConverter}, 
                                                   Mode=OneWay}">
                        <ContentPresenter Name="ContentPresenter" />
                    </AdornerDecorator>

                    <AdornerDecorator Grid.Column="1"
                                      Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=FormFieldControl}, 
                                      Path=IsReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, 
                                      Mode=OneWay}">
                        <ContentPresenter Name="ReadOnlyContentPresenter" />
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

`ReadOnlyContentPresenter`'s content is a label that's been applied the following style:

```xml
<Style x:Key="ReadOnlyFormFieldControl" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="400" />
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Controls:FormFieldControl}, 
                               Path=ReadOnlyWidth, 
                               Converter={StaticResource IsSetConverter}}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Width" 
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Controls:FormFieldControl}, Path=ReadOnlyWidth}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This works fine for about 80 controls, but when I add more controls to the form then the binding in the label style fails to find the source (error 4):

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='MyProject.Controls.FormFieldControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=ReadOnlyWidth; DataItem=null; target element is 'Label' (Name=''); target property is 'ReadOnlyWidth' (type 'Double?')
```

The same happens with the style applied to the editable part of the control. I think the issue is related to the amount of controls being processed, if I move the code of control no. 81 (failing) right above control no. 80 (working), the binding in control no. 81 works now, but the one in control no. 80 fails. I did this for several controls, and the behaviour is consistent.

I'm still not clear as to how the `AdornerDecorator` works exactly, and while investigating I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096759/using-more-than-144-adorners) that mentions a problem with having more than 144 adorners in an adornerlayer, so I removed the `AdornerDecorator`'s in my code only to find that the binding issue that was happening to controls no. 81 and over is now happening to all my `FormFieldControl`'s.

Finally, I decided to try with `ContentControl`'s instead of `ContentPresenter`'s in my control template. This works fine for all the controls in the form. I know that `ContentPresenter` is a lightweight form of `ContentControl` and that it's more suitable to use inside a content template than the`ContentControl` is. However, I don't quite understand why the bindings fail when using a `ContentPresenter` and work when using a `ContentControl`.

I also find it odd that only a limited set of controls work, and when not using the AdornerDecorator none of them will find the binding source.

Has anyone come across something similar? Is there something I'm doing wrong with the `ContentPresenter`? Or if this is expected behaviour, could someone help me understand what's going on?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought, when your form is read-only, why not just set your text box to read-only? (IsReadOnly = true)

Comment: It's not really up to me, the requirement is to show a label instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether the label just displays what's in the textbox or if it has to display a custom label but if it's the former then I think you should just use the `IsReadOnly` property as already mentioned.

You can define a custom `ControlTemplate` which hides the background and borders of the `TextBox` when it is read only to make it look as though it is just a `Label`.

Try this simple example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}"
               TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                    Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                    Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation"
                    Value="None" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                    Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth"
                    Value="120" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight"
                    Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop"
                    Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                        <Border Name="Border"
                                CornerRadius="2"
                                Padding="2"
                                Background="AliceBlue"
                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                BorderThickness="1">
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="0"
                                          x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                        Property="Background"
                                        Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                        Property="BorderBrush"
                                        Value="Transparent" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox Margin="50,25"
             Name="tb" />

    <Button Content="Switch modes"
            Margin="50,25"
            Click="Button_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

You will need the following button click handler to toggle read only mode:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb.IsReadOnly = !tb.IsReadOnly;
}
```

Here is the result when the `TextBox` is editable:

[image]

And this is what the `TextBox` looks like when it is read only.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a simple workaround. However, my control works just fine if I use a ContentControl, so the question was more related to why my control behaves different when I use a ContentPresenter instead. Apologies if that wasn't clear in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason could be this one:

```
var contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter { Content = new Button() };
var contentControl = new ContentControl { Content = new Button() };
if ((contentPresenter.Content as FrameworkElement).Parent == null)
    Debug.WriteLine("ContentPresenter won't let you get ancestors");
if ((contentControl.Content as FrameworkElement).Parent != null)
    Debug.WriteLine("ContentControl will let you get ancestors");
```

Both lines are displayed, meaning contentPresenter is one of the rare FrameworkElement not setting correctly the "Parent" property.